# Coroutine does not start in between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a main menu scene with the code

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine (FadeIn());
}

IEnumerator FadeIn()
{
    whiteFadeInAnim.Play("whiteEntryMenu");
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>whiteFadeIn.color.a==0);
    ShowMainMenu();
    Debug.Log ("Coroutine started");
}
```

`whiteFadeInAnim.Play("whiteEntryMenu");` gradually reduces the alpha of a white sprite gameobject. Then, ShowMainMenu() shows the menu buttons with some animations. The scene works fine when I play it. However, when I try to load this scene from another scene using - `SceneManager.LoadScene("menu");`, nothing happens. The menu scene is loaded but all I can see is the white sprite and the debug log does not appear. There are no errors shown either. Why is this happening?

Comment: I can't find an answer for that but I can offer some workarounds and tips. - First debug the Start and coroutine to see if they are triggering.
- Then try add`yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()` to the coroutine, maybe waiting a frame should let everything be loaded and then you can trigger the animation, you can also use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f)` if you prefer waiting time.

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment on your question, I'll post this as an answer.

First of all check if your script and the `GameObject` it is on, are active in the scene after it is loaded.(Blue ticks at the name of the `GameObject` and the script)

You also may want to try some other method than `Start()`, for example `OnEnable()` may give you the same output, as the script will be enabled at the scene start (if it is saved as an enabled script), but with that you can also reuse your script without having to reload the scene. (as it would be with `Start()`)

Also you may want to read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) to figure out any problems with the order in which the `MonoBehaviour` methods are executed.